# CASE statement in WHERE clause with != condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to figure out how to use a case statement in a where clause (with !=), here is an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 JOIN Table3
WHERE 
  CASE @fruit
    WHEN 'Apples' THEN (What would go here to return only data related to apples in Table1?)
    WHEN 'Citrus' THEN (What would go here to return data related to either oranges or lemons in Table2?)
    WHEN 'Other' THEN (return all data not related to apples, oranges, or lemons from all 3 tables) (!=)
  END
```

I've seen a few examples of a case statement in a where clause, but not one with a != condition.  Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and the sql database? would be helpful if you post your data and expected output

Comment: SQL Server.  I"m trying to filter the table, by passing a variable from SSRS.

Comment: okay... all i can say is goodluck

Answer (score 2):

A simple `AND`/`OR` combination will do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
    (@fruit != 'Other' AND Fruit = @fruit) OR
    (@fruit = 'Other' AND Fruit NOT IN('Apples', 'Oranges')
```

Comment: I see how this is checking the variable against what is being passed by SSRS, but I don't see how it is using that to filter the data (e.g. Table1.Fruit = 'Apples')

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want to evaluate other boolean expression besides equality. The `CASE` statement has two forms, the one that you're trying (always look for equality) and this other form:

```
CASE
  WHEN <boolean expression> THEN <result expression>
  WHEN <boolean expression> THEN <result expression>
  ELSE <else expression>
END
```

Answer (score 0):

just use ELSE for everything else

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
  CASE @fruit
    WHEN 'Apples' THEN (What would go here to return only data related to apples?)
    WHEN 'Oranges' THEN (What would go here to return only data related to oranges?)
    ELSE (return all data not related to apples or oranges) (!=)
  END
```

OR you can use the parameter inside the case, like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
  CASE 
    WHEN @fruit = 'Apples' THEN (What would go here to return only data related to apples?)
    WHEN @fruit = 'Oranges' THEN (What would go here to return only data related to oranges?)
    WHEN @fruit <> 'Apples'  AND @fruit <> 'Oranges'  THEN (return all data not related to apples or oranges) (!=)
  END
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I don't think my original code made it very clear what I was trying to accomplish, I have edited it for clarity.